# Sorting CSV file alphabetically using Python

Tags: python

Can someone please tell me how to sort a CSV file alphabetically in columns when the data comes from multiple variables (e.g name and age)? I need names to be displayed in alphabetical order.

Here is my code:

```
with open ("Information.csv", "a", newline="",) as CSVFile:
    for_use = csv.writer (CSVFile, delimiter=",")
    info = [[name, age]]
    for_use.writerows(info)
```

Comment: You will have to 1) read the entire CSV into memory, 2) sort it, 3) output it back into a CSV file. You can't really "sort a file" on disk.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply, that helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can read as a `dict` then sort like you sort a dict ...

```
import csv
with open('Information.csv') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)

    sorted = sorted(reader,
                key=lambda k: (k['name'].lower(), k['age'])) # sorting by name and age
```

`sorted` will be a generator that yields all items sorted

Comment: Gave me an error                                                                       AttributeError: 'DictReader' object has no attribute 'items'

Comment: Oups, remove `.items()`

Comment: **ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.** Does not work!

Comment: Oups again, moved the operation inside the `with` statement